# Is there a way to simplify conditional switchMap operations with similar subscriptions?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm subscribing to a searchbox, and based on if the value is empty or contains characters, get search results from different observables.

```js
this.myservice.searchByKeyword.pipe(
  switchMap(keyword => {
   if (!keyword || keyword.length === 0) { // true if keyword is empty
    return this.someService.GetEmptySearch();
   } 
  return this.someService.GetItems(keyword); 
  }),
  takeUntil(unsubOnDestroy$)
).subscribe({
 next: articles: Article[] => {
 // Here the result should be handled in the same way, except that if the GetItems observable is returned, I would like to do some conditional with the result.
  ...
   if (getItems was returned) { // pseudocode
     // blah blah
   }
 }
})
```

I played around with returning a nested observable with an enum to indicate that the conditional should be run or not, but I have not gotten it to work yet.

I could move the entire subscription block into, for instance a tap operator in the switchMap. But that would result in duplicate code, and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: The shown code is really confusing. Could you maybe state which service should be called and when?

Comment: It is a refactoring + optimizing job, so the code is not super readable for me either :) The original code piece used the nested subscription anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pipe to the `GetItems` call:

```
this.myservice.searchByKeyword.pipe(
  switchMap(keyword => {
   if (!keyword || keyword.length === 0) { // true if keyword is empty
    return this.someService.GetEmptySearch();
   } 

   return this.someService.GetItems(keyword).pipe(
     map((items) => // do what you want here)
   )
  }),
  takeUntil(unsubOnDestroy$)
).subscribe({
 next: articles: Article[] => {
 }
});
```

Also, it feels like the result is directly used in the template. You can store the `Observable` in your component, and use it directly using the async pipe. This will reduce code overhead with `takeUntil` and `subscribe`:

```
readonly articles$ = this.myservice.searchByKeyword.pipe(
  switchMap(keyword => {
   if (!keyword || keyword.length === 0) { // true if keyword is empty
    return this.someService.GetEmptySearch();
   } 

   return this.someService.GetItems(keyword).pipe(
     map((items) => // do what you want here)
   )
  })
);
```

Another point, considering both calls come from the same service, it feels better to do the logic with the keyword and mapping inside the service, and not in the component

Comment: Cool, but how would that work if I am dependent on some code run in the subscribe block before the getItems conditional is called?
ps, the result is used as an input to ag-grid. Is the async pipe still an opportunity?

Comment: @Anders I cannot think of a reason what would be in the subscribe block that could depend on it. Can you give an example?

Comment: you mean `articles.length === 1 && GetItems`, or `||`? Because if it's 'and', then you can do it in the same pipe/map i proposed

Comment: No need. Your solution worked if I changed the map to a tap. When I tried a map, the switchMap argument complains that it is not assignable to parameter of type 'value(: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<void>'. Using a tap circumvented that problem :)

Comment: @Anders probably because you used a `forEach` on the array, instead of the `map` function of array to alter it. You do need to return something from map, otherwise it casts to `void` :). With `tap`, this is not needed, but you might cause unwanted side-effects. Which is a bit of an anti pattern, but that's up to you

Comment: You're right again :) The items returned from getItems are indeed of type Item[ ], where Item is a custom made interface. Do you have any links as to the possible side-effects when using tap? I thought its function was to do small-scale by-effects on the primary observable chain.

Comment: @Anders I like to return new objects from any function, and not alter existing objects. It coincides with the state pattern, but it's about personal preference mostly